# How to replace multiple formulas with single one

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have this formula that I am duplicating for each column within a row:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://mysite.com", B2), "url")
```

I am wondering is there anyway to replace that formula with another so that I would use that new formula only once so it populates the whole row automatically? Something similar to what `=QUERY(Data!A2:$A)` does, it populates the whole row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
=index(if(A2:2="",,hyperlink("http://mysite.com."& A2:2,"URL")))
```

will create links with the values ​​of all the not-empty cells of `row 2` while, for a result concerning the `column A`, the formula will be of the type:

```
=index(if(A2:A="",,hyperlink("http://mysite.com."& A2:A,"URL")))
```

Comment: how would you do same for the columns?

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your new request